# JSON Object of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm pulling my hair now with this. I have this `str` variable in parent window after getting from child window with `JSON.stringify`. The group of arrays are a collection of inputs.

```
var str = {"SHOP1":"\"[[\\\"name1\\\",1,\\\"anotherdata1\\\"],[\\\"name2\\\",2,\\\"anotherdata2\\\"]]\"",
"SHOP2":"\"[[\\\"name1\\\",1,\\\"anotherdata1\\\"],[\\\"name2\\\",2,\\\"anotherdata2\\\"]]\""};
```

What I did was

```
for(var i in str) {
console.log(i); 
console.log(JSON.parse(str[i])); 
} 

//the output example:
SHOP1
[["name1",1,"anotherdata1"],["name2",2,"anotherdata2"]]
```

But it will never detect `[["name1",1,"anotherdata1"],["name2",2,"anotherdata2"]]` as an array but as string.

Is there any way to make Javascript to detect it as an array? Or is there better suggestion or alternative to this?

Comment: Theres no arr... And please format your code...

Comment: @Jonasw thanks for pointing out. Overlooked the str

Comment: What you want to get from the str and the str is also not valid

Comment: The data seems to have been passed through JSON.stringify multiple times, at least once partially. You should really fix whatever is generating it so that it doesn't stringify it multiple times.

Comment: @siva which is not valid? I am trying to iterate the arrays in the object to display all the collected data

Comment: You have stringified the array and then you have stringified your whole str object so when you get the array it will return a string. to get a string as array you have to parse the returned string again. So better you can try to  stringify it once to avoid multiple parse

Comment: *"Or is there better suggestion or alternative to this?"* Fix the code that generates the string. Don't double encode your data.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah I'll fix it soon. It will be a little complicated. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to parse it twice.  First to get the string, then second to convert it to the arrays.

```js
var obj = {"SHOP1":"\"[[\\\"name1\\\",1,\\\"anotherdata1\\\"],[\\\"name2\\\",2,\\\"anotherdata2\\\"]]\"",
"SHOP2":"\"[[\\\"name1\\\",1,\\\"anotherdata1\\\"],[\\\"name2\\\",2,\\\"anotherdata2\\\"]]\""};

for (var shopname in obj) {
  var shop = obj[shopname];
  shop = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(shop));
  console.log(shop);
  console.log(shop.length);
}
```

Comment: `unescape` doesn't do anything here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling

Comment: was about to ask why we need the `unescape`. I didn't know I've `stringify` twice, thanks @nixkuroi !